# Как узнать количество уровней прототипного наследования объекта?

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает объект и возвращает количество уровней прототипного наследования этого объекта

Для проверки:

```
const obj = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = Object.create(obj);
const obj3 = Object.create(obj2);

console.log(layersOfInheritance({})); // 0
console.log(layersOfInheritance(new Date())); // 1
console.log(layersOfInheritance(obj3)); // 2
```

Можно использовать рекурсию и метод Object getPrototypeOf.

Comment: с чем конкретно возникла проблема?

Answer (score 0):

> Можно использовать рекурсию и метод Object getPrototypeOf.

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const obj = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = Object.create(obj);
const obj3 = Object.create(obj2);

console.log(layersOfInheritance({})); // 0
console.log(layersOfInheritance(new Date())); // 1
console.log(layersOfInheritance(obj3)); // 2

//
function layersOfInheritance(obj, lv = -1) {
    const o = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
    return o ? layersOfInheritance(o, lv + 1) : lv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно (и нужно) без рекурсии:

```js
const obj = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = Object.create(obj);
const obj3 = Object.create(obj2);

const layersOfInheritance = (obj) => {
  let layersCount = 0;
  let prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  
  while (prototype !== null) {
    ++layersCount;
    
    prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(prototype);
  }
  
  return layersCount - 1;
}

console.log(layersOfInheritance({})); // 0
console.log(layersOfInheritance(new Date())); // 1
console.log(layersOfInheritance(obj3)); // 2
```

В конце вычитаем единицу, потому что цепочка наследования всегда будет заканчиваться так `obj -> ... -> Object -> null`, и насколько я понимаю по вашим выходным данным этот последний `Object` вам не нужен